# DialogFlow not working in WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, dialogflow-es

I have a given link to a DialogFlow chatbot, I need to integrate it to my Android application using WebView. 
My problem is that the chatbot client works fine with my mobile browser (chrome) but not inside my WebView, I got this error :

[image: error in The WebView]

Thanks
:)

Comment: maybe this can help you https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi thanks a lot, but I don't want to integrate the SDK, I have already a web client And I need just to open it inside my WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause it was a mistake on the url :(

Comment: Hi @Othmandroid, I am facing a issue while implementing dialogflow iframe in webview android "This application does'not work without javascript". Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi,
for me it wasn't an iframe, is it a restriction to use an iFrame ?